# Location/Distance Tracking

Tags: android, geo-location

I want to track the location of my android mobile and what all places i go in general, are there any good free programs already ?

If not I just would program a small program myself, as I want it to detect my precise location without telling or disturbing me

The sole purpose of the whole thing is to track my places from the computer a bit better and look at how much kms. I spend on going out.

Comment: Plenty of apps for that, just check my list of [Tracking apps (general)](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_tracking). Which one to pick depends on how much it should be capable of; Endomo (as Tim already pointed out) might be more than "a little overkill" :)

Comment: Something that constantly tracks you will kill your battery in only a few hours of use.

Answer (score 1):

## [Endomondo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.endomondo.android)

Endomondo is an exercise tracking application that is probably more than what you're looking for, but it fullfils all your requirements. Its features include:

- Precise tracking of your movement on the map, in addition to duration, speed, distance, calories, etc...
- Uploads the data to an online profile that you can log into to view your journey on an interactive map
- It has audio feedback, but that could be easily turned off from the settings
- It is free, and it also has a paid version with extended features

Below is an example map of a travelled route from Google Play. But again, if you are looking for an app with **only** location tracking, then this is not it

[image]